# Converting an Excel chart to a high-resolution image and vectorgraph

Tags: c#, excel, image, charts

In `VSTO`, the Excel chart can be exported by the function: `chart.export()`. But the quality of exported image is so bad and the resolution can not be selected, like: [Programmatically (C#) convert Excel to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287879/programmatically-c-convert-excel-to-an-image).

So are there any other methods that can be used to converting an Excel chart to a high-resolution image and vectorgraph in `C#`.

Comment: What type of data is in the chart? Look for Octave or GNUplot (free) or Matlab (expensive). There is nice `exportfig` package for Matlab (using ghostscript) for creating high quality pdf images.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 solutions to your problem:

1- If you manually zoom in excel before using the export fonction, then the resulting image will have a bigger resolution.

2- Just use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143437/9448877